# jQuery - How to create TreeView Menu from Array of Strings

Tags: jquery, path, treeview

I have an Array. The elements of this array is actually string paths to items:

- Category1/subCategory1/item1
- Category1/subCategory1/item2
- Category1/subCategory1/item3
- Category1/item4
- Category2/item5
- Category2/item6
- Category3/subCategory3/item7
- Category3/subCategory3/item8
- item9
- item10

I want to use jQuery to convert this to a TreeView menu. I did it with servercode both in PHP & ASP.NET C#, but just couldn't figure out how to achieve the same just using jQuery without any backend code involved.

Can someone here point me in right direction...

Thanks.

Comment: Could you post your C#/PHP/ASP.NET code?

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll want to use [jsTree](http://www.jstree.com/) to help you out here. jsTree is a tree view that is done entirely in JavaScript. It has a well-defined structure for populating the tree ([JSON](http://www.jstree.com/documentation/json_data), [HTML](http://www.jstree.com/documentation/html_data) or [XML](http://www.jstree.com/documentation/xml_data) data structure) and you can easily take those strings (within the array) in jQuery, convert them to the appropriate structure, and then have jsTree build based on your new structure.

Comment: Thanks... sounds like jsTree is the way to go. I am going to try sometime this week and keep posted....